# MairiaDB 10.11.4 undefined method `data_dictionary_header' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: mysql

```
[root@localhost innodb]# innodb_space -s ibdata1 -T test/user_info space-page-type-regions
Traceback (most recent call last):
         2: from /opt/rh/rh-ruby27/root/usr/local/share/gems/gems/innodb_ruby-0.12.0/lib/innodb/data_dictionary.rb:324:in `each_record_from_data_dictionary_index'
         1: from /opt/rh/rh-ruby27/root/usr/local/share/gems/gems/innodb_ruby-0.12.0/lib/innodb/data_dictionary.rb:278:in `data_dictionary_index'
/opt/rh/rh-ruby27/root/usr/local/share/gems/gems/innodb_ruby-0.12.0/lib/innodb/data_dictionary.rb:235:in `data_dictionary_indexes': undefined method `data_dictionary_header' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Can be used innodb_space space-lists，Unable to determine which tables have issues based on the iddata1 file

```
[root@localhost innodb]# innodb_space -f ibdata1 space-lists
name                length      f_page      f_offset    l_page      l_offset
free                1           98304       1998        98304       1998
free_frag           1           98304       1958        98304       1958
full_frag           1413        0           158         98304       1918
full_inodes         1039        2           38          101083      38
free_inodes         1           101169      38          101169      38
[root@localhost innodb]#
```